# Format dask.diagnostics progress bar

Tags: python, dataframe, progress-bar, dask

I am using dask.diagnostic ProgressBar in the following manner:

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import dask.dataframe as dd

    with ProgressBar():
        try:
            pileup_df = dd.read_csv(sorted_pileup, sep='\t', header=None)
            lists_df = dd.read_csv(sorted_lists, sep='\t', header=None)
            pileup_df.compute()
            lists_df.compute()
        except...
```

And I get the default progress bar with "#" characters.
Coming from `tqdm` I know you can format your progress bar with one of the arguments provided.
On this script I am using tqdm and dask.diagnostics ProgressBar so I would like them to appear the same.

Right now for tqdm I am using this formatting:
`"{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (Fore.GREEN, Fore.RESET)`

I went through the [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html) but couldn't figure out a way to change the progress bar's looks.

Also, if there is a way to integrate tqdm with dask I would love to hear about it-I believe it would be a better solution for me.
I checked the docs and there is mentioned only an integration to pandas.
I tried to apply the same for dask but it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/278) solved my problem.
Basically, we will modify the definition of `ProgressBar` and use the following instead:

```
from dask.callbacks import Callback
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

class ProgressBar(Callback):
    def __init__(self, desc=""):
        self.desc = desc

    def _start_state(self, dsk, state):
        self._tqdm = tqdm(total=sum(len(state[k]) for k in ['ready', 'waiting', 'running', 'finished']), desc=self.desc)

    def _posttask(self, key, result, dsk, state, worker_id):
        self._tqdm.update(1)

    def _finish(self, dsk, state, errored):
        pass
```

Then simply call

```
with ProgressBar("your description"):
    arr.compute() # your Dask computation here
```

Comment: Superb!!! I changed def _posttask to get more information since I am treating 1B+ rows: 

`def _posttask(self, key, result, dsk, state, worker_id):`
    `self._tqdm.update(1)`
    `task_counts = {k: len(state[k]) for k in ['ready', 'waiting', 'running', 'finished']}`
    `postfix_str = ', '.join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in task_counts.items())`
    `self._tqdm.set_postfix_str(postfix_str)`